# How do I sort/search the shortcut mapper in Notepad++?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

I wanted to assign a shortcut to Word Wrap, and was surprised there was no easy way to search for a specific keyword in the settings/shortcut mapper, nor could we sort by clicking on the column title.

Wanted to also assign a shortcut to increase/decrease font – is this possible? When I searched the wiki I could not find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you are in settings/shortcut mapper, enter `word` (or `wrap`) [case insensitive] in the filter, all shorcuts that contain `word` (or `wrap`) will be diplayed.
2. I don't think it is possible to assign a shortcut to increase/decrease font

Comment: When I did not see the Filter option, I checked the version and I was on 2016..so I updated and voila ! Thanks.

Comment: @killjoy The command you looking for is called 'zoomin' and 'zoomout'  - it is in Scintilla group (last tab)